# How to change the menu prompting in Ubuntu 18.04 when multiple windows of an application are open?

Tags: 18.04

In earlier versions, when switching between applications, when multiple windows were opened, no menu was displayed. Now a menu is displayed prompting for options like: "All Windows", "New Window"...

How to  get a list of opened windows only on click as was available in earlier versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to clicking on an icon of an application in the Dock of a standaard Ubuntu desktop, you can change the behavior when you click with a hidden setting `org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action`. Set it to 'cycle-windows' to have a click on the icon change to the next window. You can use `dconf-editor`, not installed by default, or use a terminal command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'cycle-windows'
```

Possible values of the setting in Ubuntu 20.04 are:

`'skip'`, `'minimize'`, `'launch'`, `'cycle-windows'`, `'minimize-or-overview'`, `'previews'`, `'minimize-or-previews'`, `'focus-or-previews'`, `'quit'`.

Not all of these may be available in Ubuntu 18.04. You may try them all and see what behavior you prefer. To reset the setting to system default, issue the command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to reboot the desktop? It does not take effect and I do not want to reboot now. Is there any command to make it effective after setting?

Comment: Should be effective immediately. Try dconf-editor so you can see which options are available to you. Or perhaps I misunderstood your question because it is actually quite unclear. I assumed you were referring to clicking icons on the dock, but your description is not clear about that. You may want to edit your question to be more specific and clear.

Comment: Yes. I was referring to clicking icons on the dock. Your understanding of my question is correct as is clear from the suggested solution. I will try to use dconf-editor and check.

Comment: I rebooted. It works now. Thanks